# Get width and height of viewport excluding scroll bars

Tags: javascript, html, css

Okay, I've read about 1000 different ideas here but no answer seems to be complete.

I have a page that scrolls both horizontally and vertically, therefore, I have both horizontal and vertical scrollbars. I want the width of the viewport EXCLUDING the scrollbar and the height of the viewport EXCLUDING the scrollbar. Please also consider padding, and margins and borders etc.

For width, I originally had `window.innerWidth` but that included the scroll bar so I came to this solution that also accounts for body margin, padding and border, `document.body.offsetWidth + parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('margin-left')) + parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('margin-right'))`

Most other solutions for height either recommend `window.innerHeight` (but this includes the horizontal scrollbar which is not good) or `document.body.clientHeight` (which returns the whole length of the page, not just the viewport.)

So, does anyone have a solution for something so seemingly trivial?

Comment: It is not trivial. Some OS only show the scrollbars on demand. Maybe you can use [scrollbar-gutter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-gutter) to make your life easier. You can also set the width of the scrollbars with CSS, but what with browsers that don't support this (yet). Also scrollbars on mobile work differently than on desktop. So this only looks trivial if you just look at your own PC.

Answer (score 0):

document.body.clientWidth and .clientHeight maybe what you're looking for.

Comment: Neither of these work unfortunately.

Comment: so, there's something wrong with the page CSS, some padding... could you check if you have reset to 0 css globals like padding, margins etc...